# Server Error: Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message, image-upload

I can't upload images.

I'm using Chrome in MacOS Monterey. The image is a snapshot. I tried to use paste, and to upload from the local storage. It's a less than 200KB jpg.

The upload image dialog shows the following error message (same as the question title ):

> Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server

Restarted the computer but still can't upload images. A few hours ago, I was able to upload an image to an answer posted on Meta SO.

Comment: I have the same problem. It shows the same error. Unfortunately, can't attach the screenshot as that service is down, lol. The image size is of very small size.

Comment: Related: [An error occurred in the server after trying to upload an image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377839/an-error-occurred-in-the-server-after-trying-to-upload-an-image-that-i-downloade)

Comment: I've escalated to staff: [Image uploading fails with "Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382854/295232)

Comment: Do we know when this error started? I guess it was around midnight, New York time.

Comment: Yeah got response like: `{"Success":false,"Error":5,"ErrorMessage":"Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server"}`
Here was my response header if it's of any help
`x-dns-prefetch-control: off
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-request-guid: ead1957a-33f6-4f0f-9676-017d6ed1045c
x-served-by: cache-syd10144-SYD
x-timer: S1665663394.265867,VS0,VE221`

Comment: We've reproduced this and are investigating the problem. Thanks for reporting it! We'll be back with updates soon.

Comment: This issue is obviously affecting all users on all sites. I've just been uploading to imgur or other image sites directly and using that link instead

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Removed a lot of "me too" and "when will this be fixed?" comments. The [status-review] tag gets it in front of Devs (and MSE has the same deal already) and a Community Manager has already commented they're aware. This post will be answered once the issue is resolved. We know it's frustrating, but commenting it's not working or wondering when it will get fixed isn't helping anything.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> It's not DNS
> There's no way it's DNS
> It was DNS

This issue has been remediated.  We've manually updated our DNS records to make sure the image upload service resolves correctly.  It's currently just pinned to a box and we are working with the vendor to make sure we have the appropriate entries in their Start of Authority.

I'll update with any final conclusions.  There is a chance we'll blip if the server we've routed to goes down or is rotated, but we're working on getting the permanent fix up in the meantime so that doesn't happen.

Thanks for the reports and your patience everyone!

**Update 1**: DNS should be fully resolved and operational.  We'll have some pingdom alerts in place, and we'll keep an eye out for any other issues that come up.

**Update 2**: The DNS fix is having trouble propagating; investigating...

**Update 3**: Remediated again.  Will continue to investigating better resilience.

Comment: For the "Record": Issue reported at T0. => Acknowledged/reproduced by Staff at T1=T0+8h. => Workaround provided at T2=T1+4h=T0+12h. => Problem solved (x) at T3=T1+8h=T0+16h. // The 8h+8h=16h feel pretty long to me for maybe not a *vital* Process (uploading Screenshots), but still... // (x) Well "problem solved" = This Answer by Staff, no Reports/Comments from Users, only the 'Accepted' Green Check from @OP...

Comment: Out of curiousity, how exactly did it manage to "be DNS"?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, our image uploads are handled via http API. There was a recent change to the service address and the wild card address didn't migrate properly.

Comment: Is it resolved? Because I am still facing this issue.

Comment: Issue is not resolved. I still can't upload images.

Comment: Even I'm unable to upload the images or gif files using Imgur links or directly browsing from the System drives, Error Screenshot - https://i.imgur.com/PXKQ5eV.png

Answer (score 7):

One of the moderators on Meta Stack Exchange [posted a workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382865) for the bug that works if you're willing to upload to Imgur directly. I'm reproducing the post here in case some readers are interested and might miss it otherwise:

> At the moment, the SE/Imgur link seems broken and ANY uploads from SE to the Imgur instance will not work.
>
> You can 'kind of' inline any image. I'd recommend holding off cause there's some advantages to the SE imgur instance that's giving issues - you can upload to imgur and get the link to the image directly like so
>
> [image: text]
>
> You can then 'abuse' the link functionality on SE by uploading it as a link and adding a !, or simply doing the link in 'raw' markdown instead of using the uploader.
>
> [image: text]
>
> for animated gifs you may need to get a link to the gif from share options BBCode link in some cases

Comment: You can `Copy Image Address` without going to a new tab, in the context menu below the `Opening of a new tab` there is such an item.